# ChartJS not updating

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got an issues with ChartJS (or my stupidity). I've created a fiddle to show the problem.

Here is a JSFiddle of the exact issue:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('somechart').getContext('2d');
var somechart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Custom Chart Title'
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
    }],

  },

});

somechart.options.title.text = 'new title';
somechart.config.data.datasets.data[2] = 5000;
somechart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="somechart"></canvas>
```

I'm trying to update the chart after it has been rendered. However I'm getting a console error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at
>   window.onload

EDIT:
The variable name did not match, I have fixed this. Still getting an error "jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined at HTMLDocument."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to have been a couple of issues:

1. The variable `somechart` doesn't exist, you named it `chart`
2. If you log out chart, you'll see `chart.config.data.datasets.data[2] = 5000;`
   will not work because datasets is an array, so you can access it like this: `chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 5000;`

Heres a new fiddle with the fixes above added: https://jsfiddle.net/8whzsLgp/

Comment: Thanks! Also I was using v 2.8.0 in that fiddle - for some reason it didn't update the title. I changed it to 2.9.3 and now the title updates. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your chart variable is named `chart` but you're trying to access it via `somechart`, which does not exist. Change the variable `somechart` to `chart`.

Comment: Doh. Fixed the fiddle. However, now I get no console error, but the chart does not update, I get an error "jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined at HTMLDocument."

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong variable for updating content replace your **somechart** to **chart** as you have initialize chart variable

**var chart = new Chart**

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1QTdQsZqGMnmNZ2LrCed_yIWUQbg4hO5s

Updated your code as below

```
chart.options.title.text = 'new title';
chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 5000;
chart.update();
```

you need to specify the index of the dataset in order to update the data.